# Popen glitch no directory found?

Tags: python, popen

I have this strange error can anyone help. It says that there is no such directory but there 100% have a look for your self.

[image]

Comment: `pycharm_projects != pycharm_projects\dist`

Comment: You are missing `dist` directory. Copy past next time.

Comment: Hello very sorry for that mistake but it still says the exact same thing.